# python logger doesn't write into file

Tags: python, logging

i write this logger

```
import logging

class ThreadLogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("ThreadsLogging")
        f_handler = logging.FileHandler("logs/thread.log", mode="a")
        f_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        f_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
        self.logger.addHandler(f_handler)

    def info_log(self, msg):
        self.logger.info(msg)
```

But after call `info_log(msg)` file threads.log is empty. I change and delete mode in FileHandler but it dosen't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers and loggers both can have levels. You didn't set the level on the logger. Add `self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` inside of your `__init__` and it will work.